# cargar un modal des otro archivo

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

estoy cargando un modal desde otro archivo cuando doy click en un boto registrar datos(abrir modal).

pero tengo un problema, la primera vez que se cargar el modal este abre sin nigun problema,
pero cuando lo cierro y quiero volver abrirlo, este me muestra como si lo hubiese abierto dos veces.
con las advertencias de id duplicados, etc.

creo que deberia haber algo que cuando ciere el modal ya sea dando click fuera de el, o en cancelar.

se limpiara el succes de ajax, no sé de que forma podria solucionar este error, agardezco sus respuestas.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ir-piku-seleccionado").click(function () {
        $('#mod').load('view/modulos/ajaxmodulos/vistamodal.php', function () {
            $('#modalRegistrarPiku2').modal({show: true});
        });
    });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen lo estoy abriendo por segunda vez, alli salen los errores y se logra apreciar que el pirmer modal esta sobre el otro modal, pero es el mismo, solo pasa cuando lo abro depues de la primera vez.

intente esto cuando doy click en cerrar, pero pareciera que no funciona es como si nunca fuese hehco click en cancelar o cerrar

```
 $("#salir-pk").click(function () {

                $("#modalRegistrarPiku2").modal('hide');//ocultamos el modal
                console.log("estoy aqui");
            });
```

Comment: ¿Que función tienes cuando le das al botón cancelar?

Comment: ese boton no tiene niguna funcion. intente hacer algo peri no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto con JQuery:

```js
$("#cancelar").click(function(event) {
    $("#modalRegistrarPiku2").remove();
});

$("#mostrar").click(function(event) {
    $("#modalRegistrarPiku2").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="mostrar">Abrir modal</button>
<br>
<div id="modalRegistrarPiku2" style="display:none">
    Hola bienvenido a mi modal <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
     
     <br>
    <button id="cancelar">Cancelar</button>
</div>
```

Si te fijas, cuando el das en cancelar y quieres volver a abrirla ya no te lo permitirá, porque hemos eliminado por completo ese contenedor, si no quieres que esto ocurra podrías reemplazarlo por un **hide()** de esta forma:

```
$("#cancelar").click(function(event) {
    $("#modalRegistrarPiku2").hide();
});
```

Y cuando lo quieras volver a mostrar se cargará con la nueva información recibida de Ajax.

Cualquier duda o inquietud hazlo saber en los comentarios, espero te sirva :D